# Display TTY in Emacs Shell mode dirtrack

Tags: emacs

Is there any way to display the current TTY when using Emacs shell mode? Right now I get around by having tty displayed as part of the prompt but this requires scrolling back

Answer (score 2):

You can display it on the mode line.

Look at the documentation , in elisp manual, section 23.4 -- `Mode Line Format`. In subsection 23.4.2 there is written how you do it: you write a form that returns the value you are interested about.

```
`(:eval FORM)'
 A list whose first element is the symbol `:eval' says to evaluate
 FORM, and use the result as a string to display.  Make sure this
 evaluation cannot load any files, as doing so could cause infinite
 recursion.
```